# maxIntegerDigits of jsf convertNumber

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I've got strange problem with `<f:convertNumber>`. When i set maxIntegerDigits to 15 and enter, say, 16 of "1"s, i get correct number with fifteen "1"s, but if i enter 20 of "1"s i get not a number with fifteen "1"s but a number with 11 "1"s and 4 "0"s, i.e. 111111111110000, and the more digits i enter the less significant numbers and the more zeros i get. Why?
Here's code snippet:

```
<a4j:region>
    <h:inputText id="numValue" value="#{MyBean.valueN}">
        <a4j:support event="onchange" limitToList="true" ajaxSingle="true" reRender="numValue"/>
        <f:convertNumber groupingUsed="false" type="number" maxIntegerDigits="15" minFractionDigits="0"/>
    </h:inputText>
</a4j:region>
```

MyBean.valueN is java.lang.Double.

Answer (score 2):

That's the nature of IEEE 754 floating point numbers. The largest value a `double` can hold is `1.7976931348623157e308` with that integer precision. Anything beyond this integer precision will be rounded.

You want to use the `java.math.BigDecimal` instead. This way your `<f:convertNumber>` will work as intented.

Comment: it didn't help. BigDecimal allows me to enter more digits (up to 19, while field is limited to 21 symbols of which only 15 can be in integer part) but then again it converts my number in some strange way, e.g. 20 "1"s are converted to 111111111110656. So i've decided to just check on maximum allowed number instead of throwing away redundant numbers. This way it works fine, besides it looks more correct way of doing such things. :)  Though i still don't understand why maxIntegerDigits doesn't work properly even with BigDecimal.